# mupen64 installation

Tags: software-installation

Hey I am a new ubuntu user, I heard Mupen64 is a good emulator for n64, I really want to install it, I went to the software centre I didn't see it only the add-ons. I went online to look for it, I found another person ask the same question but unfortunately the guy who answered the question and said that the asking for the terminal code was a bad question so he gave a link. I clicked the link and ubuntu asked what program to open it in. I don't know to find the programs and what program I need to find, I also went to the mupen64 website and downloaded it but I don’t know how to run it. can anyone help?

Comment: Use this ppa - https://launchpad.net/~sven-eckelmann/+archive/ppa-mupen64plus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install `mupen64` with:

```
sudo apt-get install libmupen64plus2 mupen64plus
```